# What library React Native do I get this result?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for how to develop the result below with React Native, in IOs and Android. So far I haven't found a solution, any recommendations?

[Result searched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idIt2.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use these libraries which i have found

1. [react-native-date-picker](https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker)
2. [react-native-calenders](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars)

in the `react-native-date-picker` you can select your date in spinner style and in the `react-native-calenders` library you can select your date in normal style.